# char string manipulation in C

Tags: c, string

My head is getting twisted trying to figure this out.

The assignment is to get a line of text from the user and then print it out in reverse including the Hex code for each character.

I thought it would have been simple, and probably is once I understand the usage.

My thoughts were, I would set up my variable using `char stg_array[80]` whuch would give me a max size of 80 char.

I would then do a

```
while( (stg_array[i] = getch() ) != '\n' )
{
    i++;
}
```

Then I would use `strlen()` to determine the actual length (I realize I already have it, just want to use `strlen()` for practice) and drop into a `for` loop that would countdown from the `strlen(stg_array)-1` and

```
printf("Array[%d] = %s Hex Value = %X", i, stg_array[i], i );
```

I understand the buffer overflow bug I could have if the user types more than 80 chars. Not worried about that right now.

What I'm getting is the `strlen()` is returning the length to the first space in the text.

If I skip the user input and just make `char stg_array[80]={"The quick brown fox."}` with a fixed `for` loop in the middle, say 10, the program crashes.

I'm thinking I'm out to lunch about how C string arrays function.

Comment: For future reference, use the `{ }` button for code instead of bolding it.

Comment: To echo @Marlon, please take a moment to [read about Stack Overflow's formatting syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I see that you initialize stg_array[80] with single quotes.
It is a string literal you need to be doing it with double quotes.
    char stg_array[80]={"The quick brown fox."}
That's probably why it crushes when you do that.

Comment: The problem is with %s in printf...you are passing a char instead of a char *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following helps!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 80

int main(void)
{
    char stg_array[MAX];
    int i = 0, j;
    int len;

    printf("Enter String : ");
    while((i < MAX-1) && ((stg_array[i] = getchar()) != '\n')) {
        i++;
    }
    stg_array[i] = '\0';

    for (j=i ; j>=0 ; j--) {
        printf("stg_array[%d] = %c / %x \n", j, stg_array[j], stg_array[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter String : this is a test string
stg_array[21] =  / 0 
stg_array[20] = g / 67 
stg_array[19] = n / 6e 
stg_array[18] = i / 69 
stg_array[17] = r / 72 
stg_array[16] = t / 74 
stg_array[15] = s / 73 
stg_array[14] =   / 20 
stg_array[13] = t / 74 
stg_array[12] = s / 73 
stg_array[11] = e / 65 
stg_array[10] = t / 74 
stg_array[9] =   / 20 
stg_array[8] = a / 61 
stg_array[7] =   / 20 
stg_array[6] = s / 73 
stg_array[5] = i / 69 
stg_array[4] =   / 20 
stg_array[3] = s / 73 
stg_array[2] = i / 69 
stg_array[1] = h / 68 
stg_array[0] = t / 74
```

Comment: Very similar to what I had but I didn't have the \0 added at the end of my string.  As a strings needs to be terminated with a \0 would that have caused the issues?

Comment: @ChefFlambe Yes that is one thing. The buffer overflow is another one. So I have added a check to that in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to fix what you give as an argument to the printf's `%X`, then you should not use `char stg_array[80]={'The quick brown fox.'}` (This should not even compile, giving you a "single character constant too long for its type" error) but `char *stg_array="The quick brown fox."` instead (I replaced the char[80] by a char* because it's more correct, but you can keep yours if you prefer).

If strlen() returns a value, it is always right. strlen() will never return the index of the first space in a string, if you think it does, you have done something wrong.